# Know which objects have "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" enabled via SOAP/METADATA API

Tags: soap-api, metadata-api, java

Is there a way to know programmatically which objects have role access enabled, i.e "Grant Access Using Hierarchies" enabled in Organization-Wide defaults?
I didn't find this information when querying the METADATA API or the SOAP API.

I can only use java code for this project, thus Apex solutions are not possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a way to get this done @nicolas42?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems that Org-Wide Defaults are on the list of components that are unable to be retrieved via the Metadata API. Here's a full list of these for your reference: [Unsupported Metadata Types](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_unsupported_types.htm)

Comment: This page seems to not be updated correctly. It is written that "Sharing Organization Wide Defaults" cannot be retrieved. However I managed to access Custom objects OWD visibility by querying "CustomObject" with the Metadata API. It returns ".object" files containing a field "sharingModel" which has custom objects visibility. [customobject.htm](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/customobject.htm)
If custom objects visibility is retrievable maybe the  hierarchy sharing is too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this option is not available neither by Apex, nor by Tooling API, SOAP API or Metadata API. So the only option to achieve this is screen-scraping.

```
public static List<String> getObjectsHavingGrantAccessUsingHierarchies() {
String u = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + 
    '/p/own/OrgSharingDetail?setupid=SecuritySharing';
PageReference p = new PageReference(u);
String x = p.getContent().toString().substringBetween('class="pbBody">','</div');
List<string> xx = x.split('</tr>');
Map<String, Boolean> entityLabelToCheckbox = new Map<String, Boolean>();
for (String xxx: xx) {
    String a = xxx.substringBetween('class=" dataCell  ">', '</th>');
    String b = xxx.substringBetween(' booleanColumn">', '</td>');
    if (!String.isBlank(b)) {
        Boolean c = b.contains('/img/checkbox_checked.gif');
        entityLabelToCheckbox.put(a, c);

    }
}
List<String> with = new List<String>();
List<String> without = new List<String>();

for (String label: entityLabelToCheckbox.keySet() ) {
    if (entityLabelToCheckbox.get(label)) {
        with.add(label);
    } else {
        without.add(label);
    }
}

System.debug(with);
System.debug(without);

 return with;
 }
```

However, this might not pass Security Review, since this is fragile as any screen-scraping methods.

Also I posted idea to get a better option https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000015AhkQAE